# Android studio: Android calling pause after activity is destroyed

Tags: android

I'm working with Android studio on an app. Everything goes well, except on one mobile: Samsung Galaxy A10. I have two of them, and on both devices, I have the same problem. I'm using an activity to do the main stuff, but I need to create another one to do reports. But, when i call to the camera activity  with startActivityForResult(), and take the picture, on return the activity is destroyed and throws the following exception:

```
E/ActivityThread: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.ruben.app/com.ruben.app.ReportActivity}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.ruben.app/com.ruben.app.ReportActivity}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4801)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4766)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:46)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

On the Android studio tab "Profiler", I see this:
[Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRTk2.png).
As you can see, ReportActivity is called and destroyed, and suddenly, android call onPause method. This error only happens on Samsung Galaxy A10. On Samsung galaxy tab A, Xiaomi mi 11 and Pocophone F1 it works well.

Here is the code from where I call the camera:

```
private void startVideoCapture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File videoFile = null;
            try {
                videoFile = createVideoFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            fileName = videoFile.getName();

            if (videoFile != null) {
                videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", videoFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 200000000L);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
            }
        }
    }
```

It happens for video capture and photo capture (obviously I call REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO for photos, and it has its own method). I have no idea why it happens. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Android version do you have on your Samsung Galaxy A10, Android 9.0 or 10?Maybe its related to Android version, not the specific device.

Also what are the versions on Samsung Tab A, Xiaomi Mi 11 and Pocofone F1?  
Maybe try with different emulator Android versions, 8, 9, 10 and see if the issue is happening there as well.

Comment: All mobiles, excepting mi 11, are using android 10. Mi 11 is using android 11

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I'm also facing the same problem.

Comment: No, sorry. We couldn't find the error.